# Duplicate key error during upsert [Explanation]

Tags: php, mongodb, key, duplicates, upsert

I am executing the below statement in a class. This code is from

```
$query  = array('_id' => $id, 'lock' => 0);
$update = array('$set' => array('lock' => 1));
$options = array('safe' => true, 'upsert' => true);
$result = $this->_mongo->update($query, $update, $options);

if ($result['ok'] == 1) {
    return true; 
}
```

However I do not understand how I would get a duplicate key error.
Can someone explain the possible scenarios and likelihood that I will receive this error?

I have been researching this extensively, cannot find my answer anywhere. So if it is on SO or any other website please share!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this resolved Jesse?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing an upsert and including `_id` in your query, you shouldn't be getting any duplicates on that key. This makes me think that you've created a unique index on `lock`, which isn't going to work for more than 2 documents because you only have 2 values for that field.

If you haven't put a unique index on lock, then you must have a unique index on a field you aren't showing here. That won't work either because on an insert, your upsert is going to set `_id` and `lock` only, any other field with an index will be inserted as `null`. If one of those fields has a unique index, then only a single document can have a `null` in that field. So when you try and insert another `null` for that field, you'll get a duplicate key error.